# Linux command line to launch gnuemacs

Tags: frames, start-up, command-line-arguments

I would like to launch Emacs by typing a command line in the terminal in Ubuntu linux. I want Emacs to open file `a.txt` in one frame and another file `b.txt` in another frame.
I tried the command `*emacs a.txt -f make-frame-command b.txt*` 
Unfortunately this command does not work. It launches one frame with a split buffer containing `a.txt` and `b.txt` and another frame with just `a.txt`

Comment: you can execute some elisp code to do that : emacs --eval "(progn (find-file \"a.txt\")(find-file-other-frame \"b.txt\") ".

Comment: Unfortunately that proposed code does not work at all. It simply opens a single un-named buffer in emacs

Comment: I just missed the last parenthesis. Try : emacs --eval "(progn(find-file \"a.txt\")(find-file-other-frame \"b.txt\"))". Shame on me...

Comment: thank you - it now works perfectly! Is there a way of passing a variable for the  file name to the command? I'd like to put this command in my .bashrc file and open a.txt and b.pdf where a and b are variable names specified by me.

Comment: fA="a.txt";fB="b.txt";emacs  --eval "(progn(find-file \"$fA\")(find-file-other-frame \"$fB\"))"

Comment: Thanks! that works nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any valid elisp code can be executed when starting Emacs with the --eval option.
For instance

```
 emacs --eval "(progn(find-file \"a.txt\")(find-file-other-frame \"b.txt\"))"
```

or

```
emacs --eval "(find-file \"a.txt\")" --eval "(find-file-other-frame \"b.txt\")"
```

do the trick.

The first --eval command is unnecessary, you can just type

```
emacs a.txt --eval "(find-file-other-frame \"b.txt\")"
```